# jqGrid trigger("reloadGrid") in ASP.NET MVC not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm not sure how to use `trigger("reloadGrid")` to refresh a [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start). I've tried many things, but none of them will get trigger to fire. I have a grid I created through ASP.NET using the MVC DLL from jqGrid.

Now I'm attempting to change the grid onload of the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myGrid').setGridParam({rowNum: 20}).trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

The trigger does nothing; however if I click the reload grid icon on the grid itself then my new rowNum setting is applied. How do I force the grid to auto-refresh (or more accurately "display") the settings I apply to it?

Comment: Are you reloading the grid before you create it?

Comment: No, the grid is fully created. I tried firing the trigger on a setTimeout to be sure. I let it wait 5 seconds after the entire page is loaded and still nothing.